# Excel - How to COPY/MOVE Unique Value With 2 Conditions?

Tags: excel, unique, conditional-statements

[image]

trying 1 conditions and it's works

```
INDEX($E$7:$E$13;SMALL(IF($H$7:$H$12="Not Paid";ROW($H$7:$H$12)-ROW($H$7)+1);1))
```

trying 2 conditions and not working

```
INDEX($E$7:$E$13;SMALL(IF($H$7:$H$12="Not Paid";$G$7:$G$12="Debit";ROW($H$7:$H$12)-ROW($H$7)+1);1))
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
{=INDEX($E$7:$E$13;
        SMALL(IF($H$7:$H$12 & $G$7:$G$12 = "Not PaidDebit";
              ROW($H$7:$H$12)-ROW($H$7)+1);
              1)
       )}
```